# How to implement rejection on MLPClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have a set of data and it's classes. I have trained a MLPClassifier to predict the class for input data and it's working with high accuracy, but now I need to implement something like a 'rejection' class. This is, if the input data doesn't fit very well with any data observed before for the present classes, then the Neural Network returns 'rejection'.
How's it possible to achive this?

Comment: The technical term for this problem is outlier detection.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at **Adaptive resonance theory**. In short, you have trained network and unusual sample appears. You may add sample into the training set and learn network again or use **adaptive resonance theory** and train learned network only on unusual pattern. **Adaptive resonance theory** can tell you, if is pattern unusual and with this info you can implement the rejection.